# Cant install 14.04 on PC

Tags: 14.04

Tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC but the downloading program says my kernel is not i86, mine is apparently only a i686. Please advise if I could use any other product.

Comment: Oh come on... see the dropdownbox here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop ? why did you not pick the one for your system? And it is not "i86". You are missing a 3 there.

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the wrong architecture installation.

You machine is a 32 bit computer, and you have downloaded 64 bit version. Please download the 32 bit version.

To help, here is the direct link to the [correct download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) for you. You can also go to the front page and click on the drop down, the chose 32 bit.

If you need any help, try looking at [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) to help with the installation process.

How much RAM does you computer have out of interest?